# Why Font Icons are Faster than Images?

Tags: css, fonts, sprite, pagespeed

I've read articles, forums posts, answers here and everyone suggests font-icons are a way to go when it comes to load times and speed of a website.

I was about to use FontAwesome for a couple of icons and the problem is large weight of a font itself (not to mention 25KB CSS unless you take what you need).

You end up with cross-browser compatible font extention list that **weighs 705KB** !! Just to use a couple of small icons on a page?

I've done those same icons on Photosohp and total file size is around 28KB. **That's more than 20 times smaller for browser to download!!** So why the heck everyone is talking about speed of font icons over images or image sprites?

Answer (score 1):

yea fonts are faster than images because on loading of multiple images multiple http request needed but for fonts they can load from CDN server, there is another reason why we use fonts because we can change font size colour and dimension easily.

refer this link 
[why Fonts better than images](https://css-tricks.com/examples/IconFont/)

Comment: but images can load from CDN as well. If we exclude CDN for this example, then I don't see how 700KB is faster than 30KB which browser has to download. And regarding caching that can be setup on htaccess for images as well.

Comment: in 30KB there is only one image. but in 700KB there are 500 images.. all are vector images so on resizing them they will not lost their quality. on that note we can also perform various operation. This is the reason why we user fonts. there is not only the concern of speed of loading.

Comment: yeah Deepak, I was looking at font as a standalone object, I should've looked at it as a library which I can edit. Now things are looking much better. But still if we're looking at regular folks who don't know editing, large font size for the sake of a few scalable fonts, which you may not want to scale at all is too high price. I'm using all CSS design now thanx to transitions and animations in order to get rid of 94KB jquery. With mobile, weight of every little peace becomes an issue. So, for first time user images will load many times faster than large font with 90% icons you won't use.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things to answer here.

First, why do people talk about iconfonts, well they are kinda old news, but the as for the reasons why they're still used they would include:

- Browser backwards compatibility
- Ease of use (especially inline with text)
- Maturity, many existing icon sets come pre-packaged in this form

Second as to the size issue, you can customize icon fonts to include whatever you need specifically, check out [IcoMoon](https://icomoon.io/) (assuming you're not already using an automater such as gulp / grunt). It'll allow you to build / manage your fonts.

Third, i personally don't use icon fonts anymore, because of 2 reasons:

1. They are affected by font anti-aliasing
2. vertical alignment is more difficult (since it's affected by line height, etc)

Instead i use SVG sprites, i also have a nifty gulp process that will let me design in illustrator, and create sprites just by saving them in a particular directory, naturally it also optimizes / compresses them.

If you want to figure out how to do this for yourself i suggest checking out:

https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-imagemin

https://github.com/w0rm/gulp-svgstore

Comment: When i say browser compatibility, it's because SVG isn't supported lower then android kitkat and IE9. Furthermore all the IE series has issues with sprites IIRC.

http://caniuse.com/#search=SVG

Comment: thanx, well frankly I never used icon fonts myself, just started designing after 3 year break and font icons was news to me as I always used images. I'll look into those resources you mentioned.

Comment: They're still valid if you need an easy fix, and are using them mostly inline with text, but yeah make sure you optimize. Also if you're coming back after that amount of time make sure you check out gulp, i couldn't live without it now.

Comment: thanx Matthew I will

Comment: Seems like icomoon is exactly what I was looking for, this will quickly shrink the size of font as i need to. thanx a lot

Answer (score 0):

For the initial load of the page, there might be more data, but fonts tend to be cached, so subsequent loads, or loads of other pages that use the same font will be faster.